# add_action doesn't work for my function

Tags: hooks, actions, user-registration

I'm trying to build a function which run when a member is registering on my site.

I am building an extranet using the Simple LDAP login plugin to use my LDAP directory so that users connect on the extranet with the credentials they are used to using with their LDAP account.

Unfortunately, in my LDAP directory, I do not have fields that allow me to fill in the "first_name" and "last_name" fields of a my WordPress users profiles. So, as the email addresses are necessarily constituted as follows: `firstname.lastname@domain.fr`, this function cuts the email address so that I can retrieve in a table the first name and the last name and, then fill in the `first_name` and `last_name` fields of the WordPress user with `wp_update_user()`;

When users log in for the first time, they actually have no account on my WordPress site. The creation of the account is done when the connection to the extranet queries the LDAP directory. That's why I would have liked to use the `user_register` action hook;

My function is in the `functions.php`.

Here's the function :

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'fill_identity' );
function fill_identity(){

    global $current_user; 
    wp_get_current_user();
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $mail_user=$current_user->user_email;
    $mail_user = substr($mail_user,0,-14);
    $mail_user = explode(".", $mail_user);
    $prenom = $mail_user[0] = ucfirst($mail_user[0]);
    $nom = $mail_user[1] = ucfirst($mail_user[1]);
    var_dump($mail_user);
    wp_update_user([
        'ID' => $current_user->ID, 
        'first_name' => $prenom,
        'last_name' => $nom,
    ]);

}
```

But when someone registers on my site, It changes nothing.
I have tested running the `fill_identity()` function from the `header.php` and the function works well, it's how I knew the problem was not my function but the `add_action`. I've tried with others actions and it doesn't work.

I'm not really familiar writing my own hooks, this one is my first. However, my `functions.php` contains a lot of functions that I've find for some others functionalities and it's works well.

Did you have an idea ?

Comment: That filter passes the user ID as a parameter, is there a reason you're not using it and instead grabbing the current user info? What exactly does this hook do? It looks like it's mangling the user email somehow. Have you tried asking about what you're originally trying to do rather than how to fix your solution?

Comment: Where is your function located? Is it inside functions.php?

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump(wp_get_current_user());die() `. just add after function start

Answer (score 0):

HI please check below code.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'fill_identity', 10, 1 );
function fill_identity($user_id){

    $current_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $mail_user = $current_user->user_email;
    $mail_user = substr($mail_user,0,-14);
    $mail_user = explode(".", $mail_user);
    $prenom = $mail_user[0] = ucfirst($mail_user[0]);
    $nom = $mail_user[1] = ucfirst($mail_user[1]);
    var_dump($mail_user);
    wp_update_user(array(
        'ID' => $current_user->ID, 
        'first_name' => $prenom,
        'last_name' => $nom,
    ));
}
```

Comment: You should explain your code a bit.